# Why is python call function not working?

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a bash function from a python script. However im only able to call the function sending all the string

This call it's working

```
call ("mongoexport -h localhost -d dbinspection -c aggtest -u seppemarotta -p seppemarotta -o aggtest.csv --csv -f \"_id\",\"total_recomendations\"",shell=True)
```

This call is not working , it says "Error parsing command line: too many positional options" . The only thing i did its sending each parameter as a vector , saving the fields in variables.

```
call(["mongoexport","-h",url,"-d",db,"-c",col,"-u",user,"-p",pw,"-o",filename,"--csv","-f","\"_id\"","\"total_recomendations\""])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're erring at the very end -- what should be the last item of the list, you've written instead as **two** items:

```
"\"_id\"","\"total_recomendations\""
```

So change it to (I'd recommend):

```
'"_id","total_recomendations"'
```

By using single-quotes around it, you don't need to escape the double-quotes inside it, making the whole, IMHO, more readable.  Anyway, the core idea is that the comma must be part of that **one** string, while you had written it instead as separating **two** strings (list items).

Comment: I see , i've just noticed it that that item its considered as one ,  well we learn stuff everyday. Thank you very much

Comment: @Giuseppe yep, the shell splits args on (non-escaped) whitespace, and in your first version that item contained no whitespace, hence, the shell did not split it.  But avoiding `shell=True` is, almost always, vastly preferable anyway.